# android image view scale animation

Tags: android, animation

hi im wanting to know how to scale animate a logo and move its position?

i have an if statement that runs some checks and then when its done i want it to scale down  an image view (logo) and move it up.

heres my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_default" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/su_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:src="@drawable/su_logo" 
        android:contentDescription="@string/cd_su_logo"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/su_shirts"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/su_shirts"
        android:contentDescription="@string/cd_su_shirts" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

heres my java

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_initialsetup);
        preChecks();
    }

public void preChecks(){
    //check for internet connection

    //check version
    String curVersion = getResources().getString(R.string.app_versionCode);
    int curVer = Integer.parseInt(curVersion);  
    String LiveVersion = "100";
    int liveVer = Integer.parseInt(LiveVersion);

    if(curVer < liveVer) Log.v("setup", "There is a new version");  
    else { 

        //scale animation


    }   




}
```

Answer (score 19):

You can do that by applying `ScaleAnimation` and `TranslateAnimation` together in `AnimationSet`

```
// Scaling
Animation scale = new ScaleAnimation(fromXscale, toXscale, fromYscale, toYscale, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
// 1 second duration
scale.setDuration(1000);
// Moving up
Animation slideUp = new TranslateAnimation(fromX, toX, fromY, toY);
// 1 second duration
slideUp.setDuration(1000);
// Animation set to join both scaling and moving
AnimationSet animSet = new AnimationSet(true);
animSet.setFillEnabled(true);
animSet.addAnimation(scale);
animSet.addAnimation(slideUp);
// Launching animation set
logo.startAnimation(animSet);
```

Comment: What's the best way to keep the ImageView showing with it's post animation attributes showing in the View?