# Animate the Cart icon on button click

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to animate my Cart Icon on the Action Bar when clicking on Add Item. As the animation, I want to zoom-in the Cart icon a little, and then zoom-out back to the original size. How can I do it?

Comment: Can you use `Toolbar` instead? If yes, you can set a custom view that contains an `ImageView` and apply scale animation this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11422421/android-image-view-scale-animation

Comment: I have added the Cart as a menu item on Action Bar. Do not know how to move it to a custom view. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try this  :

```
 ScaleAnimation scale = new ScaleAnimation(0, 1, 0, 1, ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, .5f, ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, .5f);
                scale.setDuration(500);
                scale.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator());
               yourCartIcon.startAnimation(scale);
```

Answer (score 1):

**you can check here its it has almost similar which you have required**

[Check link here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44085260/932219)

[image]