# How to change width of ImageView in runtime?

Tags: java, android

want to turn a card in my app. I have 2 `ImageViews` 1 `Cardfront` and 2 `Cardback`.

My theory ->

> 1. I change the width of the cardfront from 100% to 0%
> 2. I change the width of the cardback from 0% to 100%

I googled for solution on changing the width of am ImageView while runtime, but the solution I found don't work.

```
// Code for step 1
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = ivBomb.getLayoutParams();
int width = params.width;
for (int i = 1; i<width; i++) {
    params.width--;
    ivBomb.setLayoutParams(params);
    Thread.sleep(10); // To see the change
}
```

When I start it without the `Thread.sleep(10);`, it disappears instantly. But when I start it with the `Thread.sleep(10);`, it waits ~7s and then disappears instantly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't see the change because it is too fast. Try animating instead of reducing the size  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11422421/android-image-view-scale-animation

Comment: Make a custom Image view.

Comment: animating the view would be a better choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use animation to get the flip card effect. This [card flip animation tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html) here is for a fragment, but you can use the same animations for your views like

```
Animation cardFlipRightOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.card_flip_right_out);

cardFlipRightOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener(){
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
    }           
    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
    }           
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
                Animation cardFlipLeftIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.card_flip_left_in);
                cardFrontView.startAnimation(cardFlipLeftIn);
    }
});


cardBackView.startAnimation(cardFlipRightIn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling one of these after setLayoutParams() :
1. requestLayout()
2. invalidate()

Since, requestLayout() should be called, when view's position or bounds in the parent layout have been changed, while invalidate() should be called when view's appearance has been changed. When you call requestLayout() then onLayout() and onMeasure() methods of the view will be fired, on the other hand when you call invalidate(), then onDraw() method will be fired.